# Can I use OpenGLES3.0 on IOS just by changing the rendering context, not the header files?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-3.0

Our IOS engine has used OpenGLES2.0 for ages now, but this limits the maximum number of textures that can be bound at once to 8.  If I change to OpenGLES3.0 this raises the number on all devices to 16. I do this by changing all my

```
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
```

to

```
#import <OpenGLES/ES3/glext.h>
```

and by changing the rendering context from

```
context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
```

to

```
context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3];
```

I notice that if I only change the rendering context, then I dont need to change any code. It all compiles and works.  If I change the header files I do need to change a few lines of code.

Can I just change the rendering context ? As GLES3.0 is a superset of GLES2.0 will this work ?  Upon testing the maximum number of texture units with

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &maxUnits);
```

It has indeed changed from 8 to 16, whether I change the headers or not.

Furthermore then, what if the device doesnt supporet GLES3.0 ? I believe devices before the A7 chip don't. Can I then revert to the GLES2 rendering context, and just use the GLES2.0 headers for both ?

Yes, I know OpenGL is deprecated and I should use Metal. We're working on that, but inthe meantime can I just use the GL2 header files with a GL3 rendering context ?

Thanks

Shaun

Answer (score 0):

Users of my program use more than 50 textures simultaneously with OpenGLES2.0 and I did not notice any limitations even on old phones.
Perhaps it is worth revising the drawing technique.